# Any REST API which gives us the list of region that supports ultra disk in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-api-management

Region supported by azure ultra disks are as follows:
East US 2
East US
West US 2
SouthEast Asia
North Europe
West Europe
UK South

Need to find an API (from management.azure.com) which gives these regions supported by ultra disks to be used in my code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can right below powershell query to leverage ultra disks, you need to determine which availability zone you are in. Not every region supports every VM size with ultra disks. To determine if your region, zone, and VM size support ultra disks, run either of the following commands, make sure to replace the region, vmSize, and subscription values first:

CLI:

```
$region = "southeastasia"
$vmSize = "Standard_E64s_v3"
(Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations.Contains($region) -and ($_.Name -eq $vmSize) -and $_.LocationInfo[0].ZoneDetails.Count -gt 0})[0].LocationInfo[0].ZoneDetails
```

CLI:

```
$subscription = "<yourSubID>"
$region = "<yourLocation>, example value is southeastasia"
$vmSize = "<yourVMSize>, example value is Standard_E64s_v3"

az vm list-skus --resource-type virtualMachines  --location $region --query "[?name=='$vmSize'].locationInfo[0].zoneDetails[0].Name" --subscription $subscription
```

I haven't tried it but you can try using api like below:

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/publishers/{publisherName}/artifacttypes/vmimage/offers/{offer}/skus?api-version=2019-03-01

and write query like below:

```
--query "[?name=='$vmSize'].locationInfo[0].zoneDetails[0].Name" --subscription $subscription
```

Try and see if it helps, feel free to tag me in your conversation.

Comment: Can you provide the authentication header to be used with this API. I am getting the error as :{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}

Comment: It should be like any other Management api .